# Convert from decimal to binary, octal, hexadecimal with char array

Tags: java, arrays, binary, hex, decimal

I have converted some decimal numbers into the binary, octal and hexadecimal system. For that, I didn't have to use any collections and libraries. So now I need to change my implementation because I used String for storing the result, while I supposed to use a char array.

My current implementation:

```
public static String convertDecimal(int number, int base){
    String result = "";
    while (number > 0) {
        if (base == 16) {
            int hexalNumber = number % base;

            char hexDigit = (hexalNumber <= 9 && hexalNumber > 0) ? 
                    (char) (hexalNumber + '0') : 
                    (char) (hexalNumber - 10 + 'A');
            result = hexDigit + result;
            number = number / base;
        }
        if (base == 8 || base == 2) {
            int remainder = number % base;
            result = remainder + result;
            number = number / base;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

How can I change my implementation in order to return char[] from the method? Should I completely change the logic of my conversion algorithm?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The String class has a method [toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of a while loop, and instead of `result = hexDigit + result` do `result[i] = hexDigit` assuming result is a char[] and `i` is your iterator
Same for base 8 and 2

Comment: @BadMiscuit That shouldn't work. How do you initialize such an array? What size would you consider?

Comment: @Yash Count the digit number

Comment: You need to change the logic of your conversion algorithm because it doesn't handle negative numbers. or zero.  Write some unit tests for that first.

Answer (score 1):

`String` has a method for converting itself to a `char[]`, just use it:

```
return result.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Is it advisable to use an ArrayList of characters in such a case?

Comment: But according to the task I can't use ArrayLists or Strings, including specific methods like toCharArray

Answer (score 1):

If they want an array of char, they probably won't like just a

```
return result.toCharArray();
```

As arrays are of fixed size, one could first count the digits:

```
public static char[] convertDecimal(int number, int base) {
    if (number < 0) {
        char[] positiveResult = convertDecimal(-number, base);
        char[] negativeResult = ...
        return negativeResult;
    } else if (number == 0) {
        return new char[] { '0' };
    }
    int digits = 0;
    int n = number;
    while (n != 0) {
        ++digits;
        n /= base;
    }
    char[] result = new char[digits];
    for (int i = 0; i < digits; ++i) {
        ... result[... i ...] = ...; ++i
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this in your code:

```
convertDecimal(7856421, 16);
```

For this call and editing your code as following (I have not deleted any line, only added I have added the car[]):

```
public static String convertDecimal(int number, int base) {
char[] resultChar = new char[0];
String result = "";

while (number > 0) {
    if (base == 16) {
    int hexalNumber = number % base;

    char hexDigit = (hexalNumber <= 9 && hexalNumber > 0) ? (char) (hexalNumber + '0')
        : (char) (hexalNumber - 10 + 'A');
    result = hexDigit + result;
    int totalLength = resultChar.length + 1;
    char[] aux = new char[totalLength];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < resultChar.length; i++) {
        aux[i] = resultChar[i];
    }
    aux[totalLength - 1] = hexDigit;
    resultChar = aux;

    number = number / base;
    }
    if (base == 8 || base == 2) {
    int remainder = number % base;
    result = remainder + result;

    number = number / base;
    }

}
return result;
}
```

Yo have in resultChar[] the result inverted (in this case you get 77E125 and the char[] has [5, 2, 1, E, 7, 7]). now you only need to return it inverted.